# Why are unnecessary language files installed on my system?

Tags: language-support

Playing with hardinfo I noticed that I have more language files on my system that I use.
I use only english and german language.

Hardinfo report shows me these languages for example:
de_BE.utf8  German locale for Belgium
en_AG   English language locale for Antigua and Barbuda

Why are they on my system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems an issue with hardinfo reporting the terms *locale* and *language* rather confusingly.

I have only 2 languages installed on my ubuntu system, english and norwegian. Yet hardinfo returns a long list of all the *locales* matching 'en'.

A *locale* does not consist of the language files for a language, it is *"a set of language and cultural rules"* (quote [man 7 locale](http://linux.die.net/man/7/locale))

In fact, hardinfo shows exactly the same list as what this command returns:
 `locale -a|grep 'en\|no'`, which i suspect is what hardinfo uses "under the hood".

Comment: Why I get this update today than?  ttf-thai-tlwg (1:0.4.13-4) to 1:0.4.13-4ubuntu0.1 This is for Thai language. Also I get updates like this hunspell-de-at (20091006-3ubuntu1)

Comment: I've looked into Synaptic Package Manager. There are some packages installed that I will never use, this means I get updates for all these packages.

Comment: Regarding specific packages see the answer from @Thomas Boxley. 

However; these packages are unrelated to the *locales* being listed in *hardinfo*, which was what I were trying to convey with my answer.

Comment: good point...i try to make sure everything on my box is as specific as possible en-us.UTF-8...I leave the extra fonts in place though...sometimes I view russian/european files (subtitles for video is a common example, there are many others) that need additional accent marks - french and spanish come to mind